# If you focus on Craft (Untrained) vial feats, traits etc, does that mean you can build anything?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

If you focus on Craft (Untrained) vial feats, traits etc, does that mean you can build anything?

Ex: Craft (Untrained)
Skill Focus +3
Racial +2
Class +2
Feat +2

Answer (score 9):

You can't choose feats like [Skill Focus](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#skill-focus) for Craft (Untrained), [since per the rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/craft.html#craft)

> Craft is actually a number of separate skills.

“Untrained” isn't one of the separate skills. It's just what you would roll if you don't have the *specific* craft skill needed for a situation.

So you can improve your 0-rank Craft skill**s** by non-rank means, but you have to do it individually: each improvement would have to be for a *specific* Untrained Craft (*[item group]*) skill, not for all the infinite number of Untrained Craft skills.

For example, you could take [Skill Focus](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#skill-focus) (Craft (Weapons)), and if you're untrained in Craft (Weapons) you would get a +3 on your untrained rolls. You just can't take Skill Focus (all Untrained Craft skills).

If you find a class, race, or feat skill bonus that applies to *any* Craft skill however, that *would* apply to all attempts to use any Craft skill untrained, because the bonus applies to any such skill. You just can't use such things that requires choosing *a* skill (like Skill Focus) without choosing the exact Craft (*[item group]*) skill to apply it to.